# How to show values in data labels of Excel Pareto Chart when chart is based on percentages

Tags: excel, vba, charts, pareto-chart

I am developing a Pareto Chart for my client in Excel 2010.  They currently have a chart that shows the percentage of each category on the primary Y-axis.  Then, the secondary Y-axis is used for the cumulative percentage, up to 100%.  So far, this is a normal and easy to create Pareto.  I should also mention it is based on a Pivot Chart with 3 different Report Filters.

They wish to show data labels above each column to indicate the number of occurrences.  So for example, they may have 6 events on the x-axis:

1 - Event A, 50%, 1,000 occurrences

2 - Event B, 30%, 600

3 - Event C, 10%, 200

4 - Event D,  5%, 100

5 - Event E,  3%, 60

6 - Event F,  2%, 40

I cannot figure out how to show the data labels so they show the value of each category  (e.g. Event B would show 30% on the left axis,have a data label of 600 and the Cumulative total line would be at 80% at this point).  Please keep in mind that depending on what is selected with the Report Filters on the Pivot Chart, the name/number of categories on the x-axis will change, so I don't think adding a formula into the data label is the answer either.

I've looked everywhere (I think) for an answer, but cannot figure it out.  I'd prefer to avoid a VBA solution, but I do know how to write VBA code, so if that's the only way, a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.